# PHP: Undefined index! But it's defined

Tags: php, laravel, associative-array

I'm using Laravel but that shouldn't play a role in this problem:

I'm getting error:

> Undefined index: AutoID

in this:

```
dump($row); // outputting assoc array on screen
$id = $row['AutoID']; // getting error here
```

This is how output of array looks like:

```
array:8 [▼
  "AutoID" => "6"
  "Numurs" => "XXXX"
  "Auto" => "Opel Astra"
  "IzlaidumaGads" => "2007"
  "BakasTilpums" => "52.00"
  "KontaktiID" => "41"
  "Piezimes" => "NULL"
  "Slegts" => "1"
]
```

As you can see - array starts with index "AutoID".
Has anyone any clue why this could be happening?

Code is cut out of foreach loop, but 2 lines are really following each other and $row isn't modified anywhere in code.

Also if I try using for example $row['Auto'] - there is no error

Full code:

```
private function storeCars($arrAuto) {
    $idAssoc = [];
    foreach ($arrAuto as $row) {
        $car = new Car;

        $car->title = $row['Auto'];
        $car->plate_number = $row['Numurs'];
        $car->year = (int)$row['IzlaidumaGads'];
        $car->odometer = 0;
        $car->tank_size = (float)$row['BakasTilpums'];
        $car->user_id = (int)$row['KontaktiID'];
        $car->deleted_at = $row['Slegts'] === '1' ? \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString() : null;
        $car->fuel_usage = 0;

        $car->save();

        dump($row);
        $id = $row['AutoID'];
        $idAssoc[$id] = $car->id;
    }

    return $idAssoc;
}
```

dump of full array $arrAuto: https://pastebin.com/embed_js/taLjWgVy

I manually hide "Numurs" because that's plate number of actual cars

**Sollution:**

As you can see by accepted answer: I had some messed up character and index actually was like: "[?]AutoID".

I solved this simply by collecting only values from my array and using n-th value that was stored under "[?]AutoID"

Comment: Please post your code anyways. You may think its not relevant, but it still may be.

Comment: Use `??`, I bet $1, logic is flawed; dump the array on each iteration. Or show real code... you may use `array_*` function that takes pointer not a value and it may seem to you that no change is done to your array. Also for everyones sake code in ENGLISH, `$array['Piezimes']` looks pretty stupid to me.

Comment: Would you like to share your full foreach loop? So we can help you.

Comment: As a stab in the dark... does $id = $row->AutoID; work?

Comment: Can you dump `$arrAuto` for us?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw No, I tried it, As you see in output it's an array

Comment: @ManuelMannhardt It would have too many lines, also if I dump it it contains "AutoID"

Comment: Does the problem happen on every row you try, or just one particular row?

Comment: @NoOorZ24  'AutoID' is auto increment field?

Comment: @NoOorZ24 You can paste the output on pastebin.com as well. Please dump it, we need your help to help you.

Comment: @GreatBigBore it happens on all I guess, it happens on 1st, if I skip it - happens on secound

Comment: @ChiragPatel I'm reading it from csv file to array

Comment: Any "Undefined index" means its undefined. put the below code above this line : $id = $row['AutoID'];  and check how many rows did you missed
----------
if( !isset($row['AutoID'])) { echo 'skipped row'. continue;}

Comment: Please add an `echo` or something just past the line `$id = $row['AutoID'];`, to make absolutely sure that's where the error is happening.

Comment: @GreatBigBore Laravel shows me that it's the line where error happens

Comment: Try moving the line `$id = $row['AutoID'];` to the top, above `$car->title = $row['Auto'];`

Comment: @Shan it skips all of them

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest you post the entire `foreach()` loop. Many eyes looking at the code may find something you missed.

Comment: @GreatBigBore I tried - same error

Comment: @GreatBigBore I already did, it's under "Full code:"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167076/discussion-between-greatbigbore-and-nooorz24).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I copy the array into phptester.net I get some strange character in front of the "AutoID". There is some hidden character what messes things up.

EDIT: improved answer as per request

Comment: This is not an answer. It belongs in the comments.

Comment: @GreatBigBore, why is it not an answer? I noticed the character, so that could be the problem. I havent tested it yet, but I think that is the solution

Comment: It's not an answer because of your very own words: that **could** be the problem. That's not an answer.

Comment: Problem in key name, when I output it - seems ok, but if I paste it in editor it looks like "<?>AutoID" where <?> is unrecognised character

Comment: However, OP has found that there is a bad character. If that turns out to be the problem, then please edit this and state your case more firmly. I will advise him to accept your answer, after you've made it an answer.

Comment: Well, you tried, I'll give you that. When OP accepts your answer (he probably will), then take out "I think"

Comment: @GreatBigBore I couldn't test it because my browser hung at the time of writing, but I was pretty sure it was the problem

Comment: Be sure to upvote @Kootsj answer, and mark it as the accepted answer, if you haven't already.